# Convert Entire Column To ProperCase

Tags: excel, vba

So I know I can use the following code to change one cell's value to proper case in column B.

```
Dim Property As String

Property = ActiveSheet.range("B6").Value
Property = StrConv(Property, vbProperCase)

ActiveSheet.range("B6") = Property
```

What I need to do now is figure out how to apply the proper case function to the entire Column B.

I am guessing this could be accomplished by a loop but am unsure of the correct syntax for such a loop.

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
[B:B] = [INDEX(PROPER(B:B),)]
```

This will apply the Proper Case to the entire column at once without the need of looping.

Comment: It seems to not work if I have some values that are already proper case in the column.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  It gives an error? It changes them to all lower case?  Not working is not very descriptive.  @Jordan

Comment: It throws up about 20,000 rows instead of 200 with random values spaced out throughout, it also causes a huge delay in the macro.